# Invalid argument when building Chromium for Android

Tags: android, chromium, ninja

I've spent many h̶o̶u̶r̶s days trying to build Chromium for Android. I have tried searching but could not not find a solution.

Dependencies installed with no problems. Gclient runshooks and syncs with no problems.

Here is the error:

```
[12933/33587] ACTION //build/android:android_sdk_java(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
FAILED: lib.java/build/android/android.interface.jar
python ../../build/android/gyp/ijar.py clang_x64/ijar ../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar lib.java/build/android/android.interface.jar
ftruncate(): Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../build/android/gyp/ijar.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "../../build/android/gyp/ijar.py", line 23, in main
    subprocess.check_call([ijar_bin, in_jar, f.name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['clang_x64/ijar', '../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar', '/mnt/d/Android/Ubuntu/chromium/src/out/Default/lib.java/build/android/tmpe2uOTjandroid.interface.jar']' returned non-zero exit status -6
[12942/33587] CXX obj/components/autofill/core/browser/proto/proto/password_requirements_shard.pb.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am quite clueless at this point.

---

Some info on my setup below.

GN args:

```
target_os = "android"
```

Gclient:

```
solutions = [
    {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "src",
    "custom_deps": {},
    },
]
target_os = [ 'android' ]
```

Python version: 2.7.15

Executed command:

```
ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by making a Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine and doing everything in that instead of WSL.